# `conda update --all` without changing package's channel

Tags: python, conda

If I have an env as follow,

```sh
# packages in environment at ~/anaconda3/envs/project3:
#
# Name           Version          Build  Channel
pkg1             1.1              main   anaconda/pkgs/main
pkg2             2.2              main   conda-forge
...              ...              ...    ...
```

The command `conda update --all` gives me

```
The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  pkg2                          conda-forge --> anaconda/pkgs/main
```

The command `conda update --all -c conda-forge` behaves similar but for `pkg1`.

How to update all packages with channels remain respectively.